# Вкладки на C++ как в Firefox

Tags: firefox, c++

Как сделать вкладки на C++ как в Firefox? Пробовал изучить исходник Firefox, но ничего не понял =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [Вот](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760550(v=vs.85).aspx#creating_tab_controls) описание православного tabcontrol WinAPI.
- Есть еще 100500 разных СПО вариантов.
- Его можно нарисовать самому вручную. Это долго и так никто обычно не делает, если требуется быстро нарисовать GUI. Внутри firefox скорее всего собственная реализация т.к. это реально важная часть браузера.

Comment: но вот проблема хочу сделать как в Firefox чтобы была кнопка "+" которая передвигается с вкладками

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20050/FireFox-like-Tab-Control
Вот но это для C# и .NET

Comment: спасибо попробую разобратся